# How to update only one word from a TextView (with animation)?

Tags: android, animation, textview, android-animation

I have a TextView with some text in it, and I would like to change the last word.

What I find difficult is animating the change, with, let's say, a fading animation, without fading the other words too. Also, the text is centered, so changing that last word would require repositioning the entire last row of text too.

Example:

[image: example with 3 TextViews]

Here, the last word changes, but I don't know how to animate it.

I'm interested in ideas/theoretical solutions too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Get the textview value to a string and find the last character

```
String fieldName = fieldName.trim();
fieldName = fieldName.substring(0,fieldName.length - 1);
```

then replace it using string.replace() method

Comment: I want to change the entire word (not just replace characters) inside the TextView using an animation.